# "Gas requirement is infinite for the function" infinite gas error

Tags: solidity

I am getting the error "Gas requirement is infinite for the function" from the code I specified below. And the transaction is being reversed.
What should I do to get this flow to work?

```
function example() public pure returns(uint256){
    uint256 value1 = SafeMath.div(800, 100);
    uint256 value2 = SafeMath.mul(25, 24);
    uint256 value3 = SafeMath.mul(value1 , value2 );  
    uint256 value4 = SafeMath.sub(8000, 500); 
    return SafeMath.div(value3, value4);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you missing something, because this code works and returns 0 as expected from 4800 / 7000 = 0;

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;
import "https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/release-v2.5.0/contracts/math/SafeMath.sol";

contract TesterContract {
    using SafeMath for uint256;
    function example() public pure returns(uint256){
        uint256 value1 = SafeMath.div(800, 100);
        uint256 value2 = SafeMath.mul(25, 24);
        uint256 value3 = SafeMath.mul(value1 , value2 );  
        uint256 value4 = SafeMath.sub(8000, 500); 
        return SafeMath.div(value3, value4);
    }
}
```

Comment: But when I run it, I get a "Gas estimation failed" message and the transaction is reverted.

Comment: Interesting, what environment are you using. I tried this code as is in remix without an issue.

Comment: I'm using remixes. I run the code as below and I get the value 0.

Answer (score 0):

// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;
import { SafeMath } from "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/math/SafeMath.sol";
contract TesterContract {
using SafeMath for uint256;
function example() public pure returns(uint256){
uint256 value1 = SafeMath.div(800, 100);
uint256 value2 = SafeMath.mul(25, 24);
uint256 value3 = SafeMath.mul(value1 , value2 );
uint256 value4 = SafeMath.sub(8000, 500);
return SafeMath.div(value3, value4);
}
}